# CD to a Volume Serial Number (VSN) in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Briefly, is there a way to magically use `cd` following by a *volume serial number* instead of drive letter?

Generally, when I open command prompt and want to move into a drive like `E:` I would enter the following command:

```bat
cd /d E:/
```

I'm writing a batch script to copy a file into my flash drive, but I don't have the drive letter.
Instead, I have the volume serial number, e.g.: `123456`

I get the drive letter from volume serial number by `wmic` command:

```bat
wmic LogicalDisk where VolumeSerialNumber=123456 get Name
```

output is:

```bat
Name
E:
```

and vice versa:

```bat
wmic LogicalDisk where Name="E:" get VolumeSerialNumber
```

and output is:

```bat
VolumeSerialNumber
123456
```

So, either I have to store this returned drive letter by `wmic` in a variable (in Shell I would simply `grep` and store it, but I have no idea how to do it in batch file) and move to the volume using that variable, or I find a way to directly move into a volume by its serial number like:

```bat
cd #123456#
```

and magically it goes to drive `E:`.

I would prefer not to use `wmic` as it's so slow to query the volume serial number, I know my flash drive's serial number is static and won't change between systems.

I wish I find a way to directly move into a volume by its serial number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how you know the Volume Serial Number, and that it is Static. The VSN is created each time the volume is formatted, _(based on the time data)_. Have you deliberately used some utility to set the VSN? If so, what in particular led to your decision? instead of just using a Volume Label.

Comment: @Compo I wrote the flash drive firmware, VSN is set to a number statically. So when I mount the volume I know the VSN but I don't have the drive letter. Windows always uses drive letter in cmd not VSN, at least as far as I know. I'm looking for a way to directly use VSN because wmic is so slow for my operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you really know what is the Volume Serial Number (VSN) in your USB flash drive (as it is created each time the volume is formatted), then here is a possible solution:

```bat
@echo off

wmic LogicalDisk where VolumeSerialNumber="123456" get Name > VSN.txt
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A IN ('type VSN.txt') do @set "vsn=%%A"
set "diskletter=%vsn: =%"
del VSN.txt
cd /d %diskletter%
rem [do whatever you want]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=\" %%A In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"'
) Do Vol %%A 2>Nul|Find "XXXX-XXXX">Nul&&(CD /D %%A&GoTo :Next)
Exit /B

:Next
Echo Your current directory is %CD%
Pause
```

*You would obviously replace the code under `:Next` with your specific code, and `XXXX-XXXX` with your case sensitive serial number.*

**[Edit]**
If all you're doing is copying a file, then even using `WMIC`, you should be able to do that without changing directory:

```bat
@For /F Skip^=1 %%A In ('"WMIC LogicalDisk Where (VolumeSerialNumber='XXXXXXXX') Get DeviceID 2>Nul"') Do @For %%B In (%%A) Do @Copy "A File.ext" "%%B\"
```

*You would obviously change `XXXXXXXX` to the serial, (without a hyphen), and `"A File.ext"` to the file you're copying.*

A similar method using `Find`, `MountVol` and `Vol` can also be used:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=\ " %%A In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"') Do @For /F %%B In ('Vol %%A 2^>Nul^|Find "XXXX-XXXX"') Do @Copy "A File.ext" "%%A\"
```